# How to deal with StateFlow observers' boilerplate

Tags: android, mvvm, android-viewmodel, observers, boilerplate

It is popular to use MVVM in our projects. However, there is one thing I can't handle. When I observe StateFlow/SharedFlow or LiveData my Fragment/Activity looks so ugly and grows with repeatings. So it becomes difficult to read. For example:

```
orderDetailVM.order.collect {
    when (it) {
        is Resource.Loading -> {
            showLoading()
        }
        is Resource.Error -> {
            showSnackBar()
            hideProgress()
        }
        is Resource.Success -> {
            it.data.let { order ->
                setUpViews(order)
                hideLoading()
            }
        }
    }
}

orderDetailVM.deliver.collect {
     when (it) {
        is Resource.Error -> {
           showError()
        }
        is Resource.Success -> {
           pref.removeOrderData(args.orderId)
           findNavController().popBackStack()
        }
     }
}
```

And it is not over. If I have 4 of these kinds of observers my Fragment/Activity will grow even more and so on. How to handle this inside ViewModel and show Views according to State?